# REST API: How to send a push message to one contact by contactID or contactKey?

Tags: rest-api, contactbuilder, push

I'm writing integration tests for our mobile app and we would like to check how we receive push inbox messages for new users after registration.

I've found the call to send messages for added ListIds but I haven't found how to modify existing Filter lists with new registered contacts.

So my question is about the possibility to send a **push message** to one contact by **contactID** or **contactKey** instead of ListId.
If no, so how to modify existing or create a new one Filter list via REST API? The sending by deviceId doesn't suit me.